# Get-childitem fails when imported on a module

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, get-childitem, powershell-4.0

My Scripts were working OK until I've tried to work with `Mount-VHD` and use `Get-ChildItem` with the mounted volumes using personal functions that are stored on an external module.

My Script does the following:

```
import-module create-vm.psm1 -force
```

Inside this module I'm mounting a VHD file and using `Get-ChildItem` to check for the existence of some system files (in this case is the `pagefile.sys`).

But my `Get-ChildItem` fails with a rare error, because it says that doesn't recognize parameters like `-hidden` or it doesn't recognize the drive letter, etc. or it fails with the other parameters.

As workaround I've copied the function on the main body script and then it works.

Then as you could see my problem only happens when I try to use the function when is loaded from an external module.

Do you know the reason? and how to fix it?

Comment: You'll need to show your code and the exact error if you expect anyone to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro this with the following module:

test.psm1

```
#requires -Modules Hyper-V
#requires -RunAsAdminstrator

$vhd = 'E:\VirtualMachines\PowerShellDscExp\Virtual Hard Disks\PowerShellDscExp.vhdx'

function ListHiddenVhdFileSystemEntry {
    $disks = Hyper-V\Mount-VHD $vhd -PassThru | Get-Disk
    $disks | Get-Partition | Foreach {Get-ChildItem "$($_.DriveLetter):" -hidden}
}
```

I get these results:

```
30# Import-Module .\test.psm1
31# ListHiddenVhdFileSystemEntry


    Directory: L:\


Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
d--hs     7/20/2014  3:13 PM        <DIR> Boot
d--hs     7/20/2014  1:16 PM        <DIR> Recovery
d--hs     12/3/2014  7:39 PM        <DIR> System Volume Information
-arhs     3/18/2014  4:14 AM       398356 bootmgr
-a-hs     6/18/2013  6:18 AM            1 BOOTNXT
-arhs     7/20/2014  3:13 PM         8192 BOOTSECT.BAK


    Directory: m:\


Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
d--hs     3/18/2014  4:46 AM        <DIR> $Recycle.Bin
d--hs     8/22/2013  8:45 AM   <JUNCTION> Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
d--h-     8/22/2013  8:45 AM        <DIR> ProgramData
d--hs     7/20/2014  2:45 PM        <DIR> System Volume Information
-arhs     3/18/2014  4:14 AM       398356 bootmgr
-a-hs     6/18/2013  6:18 AM            1 BOOTNXT
-a-hs     7/20/2014  4:20 PM   1207959552 pagefile.sys
-a-hs     7/20/2014  4:20 PM    268435456 swapfile.sys
```